# A nonmeasurable set on $\mathbb{R}^{\left[0,\infty\right)}$.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\left\{ X_{t}\right\} _{t\geq o}$ the canonical version of Brownian
motion, i.e., if we consider $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}^{\left[0,\infty\right)}$
the set of the real valued functions on $\left[0,\infty\right)$ and
for each $t\geq0$, $X_{t}\left(\omega\right)=\omega\left(t\right)$
and $\mathcal{F}:=\sigma\left\{ \omega\in\Omega|X_{t_{1}}\left(\omega\right)\in B_{1},\ldots,X_{t_{k}}\left(\omega\right)\in B_{k},B_{i}\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right\} $
then the process $\left\{ X_{t}\right\} _{t\geq o}$ is called the
canonical version of Brownian motion. Proof that

$$A=\left\{ \omega\in\Omega|\sup_{a\leq t\leq b}X_{t}\left(\omega\right)<c\right\} \notin\mathcal{F}$$,

for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

I cheked Introduction to Stochastic Integration-Kuo Hui-Hsiung, but
here there is a particular case. However, I think I have to find a
nonmeasurable set on $\mathcal{F}$
and then proceed in the similar way, but I have been unable to make
any headway in that respect.

Comment: Hint: Elements of $\mathcal F$ depend on $X_t$ for $t$ in at most a countable subset of $[0,\infty)$. Your set $A$ does not.

Comment: Eugenio: Did you reach an answer, based on my hint?

Answer (score 2):

In order to retire that question, here's Did's comment as an answer.  Someone please upvote.

> Hint: Elements of $F$ depend on $X_t$ for $t$ in at most a countable subset of $[0,\infty)$. Your set $A$ does not.